# JSONModel bound to List in a dialog is showing last object of the json array for all rows of the list

Tags: sapui5

I can't find the problem in my code. The number of rows is always correct, but it only shows the values of the last object in the array of the binding. I'm using the correct aggregation `<items>` so that's not the issue. Maybe (I hope) I'm just overlooking something.

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<Dialog title="{i18n>selectionTitle}" horizontalScrolling="false">
    <beginButton>
        <Button text="{i18n>closeSelectionButton}" press="handleCloseSelectedTrainings"/>
    </beginButton>
    <endButton>
        <Button type="Accept" text="{i18n>submitSelectionButton}" press="handleSubmitSelectedTrainings"/>
    </endButton>
    <content>
        <List noDataText="Empty" items="{selectedTrainings>/}" mode="Delete" delete="handleDeleteSelectionItem">
            <items>
                <CustomListItem >
                    <HBox>
                        <core:Icon size="2rem" src="{icon}" class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom"/>
                        <VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom">
                            <Text text="{Title}" />
                            <Label text="{Type} {= ${Begda} ? ${Begda}.toLocaleDateString() : '' }"/>
                            <HBox>
                                <CheckBox text="{i18n>selectionMgrApproved}" selected="{Approved}" />
                            </HBox>
                        </VBox>
                    </HBox>
                </CustomListItem>
            </items>
        </List>
    </content>
</Dialog>
```

[image: Model's data when list is shown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using named model **selectedTrainings** for items bindings and you forgot to put a model name into CustomListItem elements. Put a model name into bindings like this:

```
<Text text="{selectedTrainings>Title}" />
```